# how to check if ctrl key is released (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

How do I check if left ctrl key is released in pygame? I saw the documentation, but following code didn't work for me:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:    # this is not working!
        print("Left control is released")
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what is the proper way of checking it?

Comment: Try with this code and let us know it is working or not.
`if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
        print("Left control is released")`

Comment: Added some explanation with code buddy, Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant for the left control key is `K_LCTRL`. Therefor you have to check if the `key` attribute of the event object is `K_LCTRL`:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
            print(f'release {pygame.key.name(event.key)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to match the event key with the left control key value.

And so your final code look like:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
     if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
         print("Left control is released")
```